# SearchDelegate não voltar para a página em modo de release

Tags: flutter, dart

Eu tenho este código no SearchDelegate

```
class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate<String> {

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: (){
          query = "";
        },
      )
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: (){
        close(context, "");
      },
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
   close(context, query );
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();        
  }

}
```

Quando eu executo no modo de debug, ele funciona corretamente. Mas quando executo em modo de release, ao confirmar a pesquisa, ele não retorna para a página que chamou de o Search, apenas retorna o container, mesmo com o "close(context, query );" antes no buildResults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não consegui resolver este problema em especifico, realmente busquei qualquer solução possível, mas parece te haver com a forma que o flutter gera o apk em release.
No meu caso eu apenas desisti de usar o showSearch com SearchDelegate, e criei um Appbar customizado como um SearchBar. Vou deixar abaixo alguns links que baseei

Esse foi o que mais usei como exemplo

https://github.com/ahmed-alzahrani/Flutter_Search_Example

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658208/custom-appbar-flutter

Essa opção eu não usei mas achei interessante por ser uma outra opção de otimizar seu SearchBar
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_search_bar